# How to access a VPN server with a private IP address?

Tags: vpn

I'm new to VPN so please bear with me if I do any mistake. Earlier I also posted this question but no luck.

**What I know**: How to create a VPN connection on the client.

**What I want**: In order to access the server I need its IP address but since I'm accessing the company's server, the IP address of the server is not public, but private. The ISP has given five set of public IP addresses to the company, but I don't know how to give that public IP address to the server or any other peer connected to the server. It's a small firm so the server does not have any DNS on the Internet.

Please give me some suggestions. If possible give me some videos as well giving a complete description of the process. You can also suggest me some books but only on Windows setup and not for Linux. In some books I have also studied [OpenVPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) and closeVPN, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reconfigure your router to forward ports from public IP addresses to the server private IP address.

Traffic goes:
Internet public IP address (one of five IP addresses the ISP provided you) -> router -> server (private IP address).

Depending on your needs, you need to forward the following ports from the public IP address to the server private IP address on the router side:

PPTP VPN uses TCP Port 1723

IP Protocol 47 (GRE)

L2TP: UDP Port 1701

IPSec: UDP Port 500

Pass IP protocol 50 and 51.

Note: 47 is a protocol number and not a TCP port. The protocol name is [GRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation). The Generic Route Encapsulation (GRE) protocol is used in conjunction with Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol ([PPTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol)) to create virtual private networks (VPNs) between clients or between clients and servers. It'll make a big difference when configuring your firewall or router.

Note: On the client side, when you configure the VPN client, you need to use the public IP address.

Note: If you have a web based configured router ([Linksys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys), [Netgear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netgear#Product_Range), [Firebox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WatchGuard), [SonicWALL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonicWALL), etc.) it's pretty simple.

But if you have a Cisco ([PIX series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_PIX) or similar) it is a different story.
You can configure cisco using the console COM port configuration or a Cisco web based manager.
And on the client side use Cisco VPN client to connect.

Videos:

- [Server setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YvHo7dbWUY)
- [Cisco PIX 501-506 setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuDbHCZwzlM)

What kind of router do you have?

Comment: ok let me make it more clear..

Comment: we have a linksys router and a switch.through the switch all the computers are connected through LAN and they have been assigned private IPs.

Comment: Ok, what kind of linksys model? Do you have linksys router on other end too?

Comment: I m sorry its not linksys router It is WRT354 NETGEAR router.

Comment: as you told me that i need to forward the ports from public ip to private.how can i do that.my server is connected to switch only which in turn is connected to the netgear router.

Comment: please check one more time router brand and model, there are not WRT354 Netgear There is WRT54 Linksys.

Comment: ok its wgr614 netgear

Comment: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Netgear/WGR614/default.htm

Comment: here is guide to setup port forwarding http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Netgear/WGR614/default.htm

Comment: u have been very patient with me..thnx for ur response..i ll follow these links nd if i need ny help i ll let u know

Comment: i m at home when i ll reach office then i ll perform these steps

Comment: in the link you have provided me there are two port numbers starting port and end port.how would i know about these ports

Comment: As you see one the picture is answering your question. the start port and end port are the same. Start port: 1723 End port 1723 for PPTP

Comment: so do i need to do only PPTP?

Comment: i mean do i need to add only one service nameas pptp?

Comment: i have added the service with the following details

Comment: service name-pptp-vpn service type-TCP starting and Ending port-1723 server IP address-192.168.1.26...now my ISP has given us five public IPs..so which public IP would be assigned to this server.

Comment: do i need to create any vpn connection in my server to access it through client

Comment: on my server end i have made some changes...opened server manager>Roles>right click>click on routing and network enable>assigned the list of public IPs addresses..when i try to connect it through client having windows 7 it gives me an error 800

Comment: point to check: server side: account what you want to allow VPN: properties:Allow remote access. on the server web browser: www.checkmyip.com what is IP address? On the client: VPN IP address has to be the same as result from www.checkmyip.com Account has to be same as you allow remote access on the server. Check it First:)

Comment: OK i ll do it..you seem to be genius in networking..do you write books or do you have some links which can give me full learning about VPN...i want to become an expert in that area and i guess you can give me best guidance.

Comment: are you on facebook or anyother social website?